# Spring hateoas and java 8: am I forced to throw exception?

Tags: java, java-8, spring-hateoas

I just want to add links to my response, so the following code in java 7 is perfectly fine:

```
for(PetModel pet : pets){
    pet.add(linkTo(methodOn(PetController.class).getPetById(pet.getId())).withSelfRel());
}
```

This one forces me to handle the exception that getPetById could throw, even though it will never do that in this snippet:

```
pets.forEach( (pet) -> pet.add(linkTo(methodOn(PetController.class).getPetById(pet.getId())).withSelfRel()));
```

why is that?

Comment: because you are using a lambda, a `Consumer` to be specific (what does `forEach` take as input?) and that `Consumer` does not declare to throw an Exception in it's `accept` method.

Comment: isn't there any other method to just "decorate" the pet with that new link?

Comment: surround with `try/catch`

Comment: So that's the _why_. But probably also worth mentioning that you'd only be 'forced' to handle this exception if you declared a `throws` clause on `getPetById`: if you didn't, your problem would disappear. Quite a lot of the Spring ethos is about leading you away from checked exceptions towards unchecked ones. And what's the point of throwing checked exceptions from controller handler methods? They're invoked directly by the framework. How are you ever going to wrap a `try... catch` around them?